# how can I use backslash to backreference regex groups in java replaceAll()

Tags: java, string, replace

for example:

```java
String s = "1/14/2017".replaceAll("^(\\d{1,2})/(\\d{1,2})/", "$2/$1/");
```

this Java code will switch the place of '1' and '14'.

but The form that i want is below, unfortunately Java not supported this form

```java
String s = "1/14/2017".replaceAll("^(\\d{1,2})/(\\d{1,2})/", "\2/\1/");
```

Is there any other tool can support this form?

Comment: Hello, could you provide an example input and an example output?

Comment: You can't do that, because the `String#replaceAll` API does not support it.

Comment: Title: "*how can I use backslash ... in java replaceAll()*" -> you cannot! Body: "*Is there any other tool can support this form?*" -> different question (often closed since opinion based, [point 3](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that.  And although it is not processed as `back references` by the regex engine it is first a feature of the encoding of characters in a string.

If the engine supported it, you would need to encode it as `\\\\2/\\\\1/` (or the real ugly `\\\62\\\61`) because `\` is the String escape character and what follows is taken to be raw input.  So `System.out.println("\101")` would print the letter `A`.

But then the engine doesn't support the aforementioned alternative encoding because then the replacement pattern is taken to be just a String of `"\2/\1/"` which isn't what you want.

I would imagine the `$` was chosen as it has no special meaning outside of a regular expression and is an easier way to encode a back reference indicator than escaping backslashes.  But I have no evidence to support that reasoning.